# A boss who rejects questions, or chooses not to discuss reality

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

What word would describe, "a boss who rejects questions, or chooses not to discuss reality"? He consistently defers to a lighter topic, or flat-out avoids contact.

Comment: Must the word describe a _boss_? Or can it describe _any_ individual who consistently dismisses hard questions and instead defers to lighter topics?

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to describe someone who is hiding information, or someone who is an imposter -- who doesn't really know how to do the job he's given.

Comment: No, the word does not need to describe a "boss", specifically. I was giving context, without clarification. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I confess, that  I need to be clearer in my communication. The gracious answers which I have received, drive me back to re-think the question. – adc

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word ***ostrich***. In addition to the obvious bird definition, it is also used in a metaphoric sense, applied to the kind of people you describe. From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ostrich#ostrich_5):

> ostrich (*n.*) someone who pretends that an unpleasant situation or problem does not exist

NOAD defines it as:

> ostrich (*n.*) a person who refuses to face reality or accept facts

and [AH](https://www.wordnik.com/words/ostrich) defines it as:

> ostrich (*n.*) one who tries to avoid disagreeable situations by refusing to face them

One blogger called out just such a boss in a very unflattering way:

> *Her boss is an "ostrich" boss who does not want to be bothered, his goal in life is to do as little as possible and collect his enormous paycheck every other week*. ([Source](http://www.jobschmob.com/stories/bosses-from-hell/399))

Even the Urban Dictionary has an entry about an [*ostrich manager*](http://www.urbandictionary.com%2Fdefine.php%3Fterm%3DOstrich%2Bmanager).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is close to the thought I tried to convey.

Answer (score 0):

The boss tries to cover up the reality of the matter.
He/she is unable to give a satisfactory answer so they are afraid of facing up to the reality.
The boss is arrogant.
The boss does not possess adequate skills and intellectual capacity to answer challenging questions.

Answer (score 0):

**over-promoted** see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle which broadly states:

"The Peter principle is a concept in management theory formulated by Laurence J. Peter in which the selection of a candidate for a position is based on the candidate's performance in their current role, rather than on abilities relevant to the intended role. Thus, employees only stop being promoted once they can no longer perform effectively, and "managers rise to the level of their incompetence."

Answer (score -1):

You are describing a boss who is in

> **denial**
>
> de·ni·al
>
> dəˈnīəl/
>
> noun
>
> noun: denial
>
> the action of declaring something to be untrue.
>
> "she shook her head in denial"
>
> synonyms:  contradiction, refutation, rebuttal, repudiation, disclaimer; negation, dissent
>
> "the reports met with a denial"
>
> the refusal of something requested or desired.
>
> "the denial of insurance to people with certain medical conditions"
>
> synonyms:  refusal, withholding; rejection, rebuff, repulse, veto, turndown; formal declination
>
> "the denial of insurance to certain people"
>
> a statement that something is not true.
>
> plural noun: denials
>
> "official denials"
>
> synonyms:  contradiction, refutation, rebuttal, repudiation, disclaimer; negation, dissent
>
> "the reports met with a denial"
>
> PSYCHOLOGY
>
> **failure to acknowledge an unacceptable truth or emotion or to admit it into consciousness, used as a defense mechanism.**
>
> "you're living in denial"
>
> short for self-denial.
>
> disavowal of a person as one's leader.
>
> [google: denial](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=denial)

Comment: Thank you. I confess, that although helpful, I need to be clearer in my communication. The gracious answers which I have received, drive me back to re-think the question.